# How to capture a string between signs in lua?

Tags: lua

how can I extract a few words separated by symbols in a string so that nothing is extracted if the symbols change?
for example I wrote this code:

```
function split(str) 
 result = {};
for match in string.gmatch(str, "[^%<%|:%,%FS:%>,%s]+" ) do
 table.insert(result, match);
end

return result
end
--------------------------Example--------------------------------------------
str = "<busy|MPos:-750.222,900.853,1450.808|FS:2,10>"

my_status={}

status=split(str)

for key, value in pairs(status) do
    table.insert(my_status,value)
end

print(my_status[1]) -- 
print(my_status[2]) -- 
print(my_status[3]) -- 
print(my_status[4]) -- 
print(my_status[5]) --
print(my_status[6]) -- 
print(my_status[7]) --
```

output :

```
busy
MPos
-750.222
900.853
1450.808
2
10
```

This code works fine, but if the characters and text in the str string change, the extraction is still done, which I do not want to be.

If the string change to

```
str = "Hello stack overFlow"
```

Output:

```
Hello
stack
over
low
nil
nil
nil
```

In other words, I only want to extract if the string is in this format: `"<busy|MPos:-750.222,900.853,1450.808|FS:2,10>"`

Comment: `string.gmatch(str, "[%+%-%.%w%d]+" )`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not what I want

Comment: I think you summed it up nicely yourself: "I only want to extract if the string is in this format (...)" That's exactly the solution you're looking for, rather than creating a pattern that extracts components of the expected input, write a pattern that understands the input as a whole.

Comment: I'm a little new in lua, can you give me an example to see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lua patterns, you can use captures, which are perfect for things like this. I use something like the following:

```
--------------------------Example--------------------------------------------     
str = "<busy|MPos:-750.222,900.853,1450.808|FS:2,10>"     
local status, mpos1, mpos2, mpos3, fs1, fs2  = string.match(str, "%<(%w+)%|MPos:(%--%d+%.%d+),(%--%d+%.%d+),(%--%d+%.%d+)%|FS:(%d+),(%d+)%>")     
print(status, mpos1, mpos2, mpos3, fs1, fs2)
```

I use `string.match`, not `string.gmatch` here, because we don't have an arbitrary number of entries (if that is the case, you have to have a different approach). Let's break down the pattern: All *captures* are surrounded by parantheses `()` and get returned, so there are as many return values as captures. The individual captures are:

- the status flag (or whatever that is): `busy` is a simple word, so we can use the `%w` character class (alphanumeric characters, maybe %a, only letters would also do). Then apply the `+` operator (you already know that one). The `+` is *within* the capture
- the three numbers for the `MPos` entry each get `(%--%d+%.%d+)`, which looks weird at first. I use `%` in front of any non-alphanumeric character, since it turns all magic characters (such as `+` into normal ones). `-` is a magic character, so it is required here to match a literal `-`, but lua allows to put that in front of *any* non-alphanumerical character, which I do. So the minus is optional, so the capture starts with `%--` which is one or zero repetitions (`-` operator) of a literal `-` (`%-`). Then I just match two integers separated by a dot (`%d` is a digit, `%.` matches a literal dot). We do this three times, separated by a comma (which I don't escape since I'm sure it is not a magical character).
- the last entry (`FS`) works practically the same as the `MPos` entry
- all entries are separated by `|`, which I simply match with `%|`

So putting it together:

```
        start of string: %<                                                                     
           status field:   (%w+)   
              separator:        %|
   MPos (three numbers):          MPos:(%--%d+%.%d+),(%--%d+%.%d+),(%--%d+%.%d+)
              separator:                                                        %|
FS entry (two integers):                                                          FS:(%d+),(%d+)
          end of string:                                                                        %>
```

With this approach you have the data in local variables with sensible names, which you can then put into a table (for example).

If the match failes (for instance, when you use `"Hello stack overFlow"),` nil` is returned, which can simply be checked for (you could check any of the local variables, but it is common to check the first one.

Comment: Thank you for your full explanation :)